# Read CSV pandas function

Tags: python, pandas, read-csv

Hi everyone I'm trying to read a CSV file with the pandas function like in the next line.

```py
import pandas as pd
GDP = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/erics/Downloads/world_bank.csv')
```

But when I run the code it goes smoothly without errors but the variable GDP is not defined, does anyone have any idea of what it's happening?

[image]

This is the file I want to read.

Comment: What is the issue? You say it goes smoothly without errors, so what do you need?

Comment: sorry I just write the error

Comment: Your file was never read into a datagrams that's why GDP is not defined.

Comment: Also, please post the code where this happens and the full error message to make it a complete question with all information someone may need to help you.

Comment: What do you mean with the variable GDP is not defined? Do you get any errors? Anyways, you most likely want to use the [`skiprows`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) parameter: `pd.read_csv("path/to/file.csv", skiprows=4)`.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**:

Change your file path, the format looks wrong

```
GDP = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\erics\Downloads\world_bank.csv')
```

Comment: If OP is using MS Windows then `/` separator would be accepted.